# Iterator count in _Underscore

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to create several beats in a measure (using SVGs), and place them beside each other.   I am a bit confused how to keep track of the iterator in underscore.js to use in the function itself.

Here is what I have :

```
_.each(beats, function(beat) {
      // create a beatview
      var measurePassingToBeatViewParamaters = {
        beatXLocation: beatXLocation 
        // i want this to be something like beatXLocation: beatXLocation * beatCountIterator 
      };

      new beatView(measurePassingToBeatViewParamaters); //backbone View
      //  then somewhere increase the beatCountIterator ++;
    }, this);   //this is a measure
```

Comment: Have you checked out [the docs](http://underscorejs.org/#each) already?

Comment: Yes,   it say that the iterator (in my case is a function) is called with three arguments (element, index, list).   I want the index argument, but the example they give does not show how I access that argument.   I tried naming declaring the function to a `variable` and then calling it as `variable.index`, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go](http://underscorejs.org/#each).
"*Each invocation of iterator is called with three arguments: (element, index, list).*"

**Edit:**

```
_.each(beats, function(beat, index)
```

Or:

```
_.each(beats, function(beat) {
  index = arguments[1];
```

Sorry if it's not what you meant.

Comment: I am aware of the doc, but how do you access the invoked index argument?

Comment: To also have access to the list as well, you would do: `_.each(beats, function(beat, index, list) {...}`?

Comment: Eeyup. This flexibility comes from the fact that in javascript, functions don't have a defined list of arguments. What you're doing with `function(beat){...}` is simply a shortcut for `function(){beat=arguments[0];...`}. The variable *arguments* stores all the arguments within an array.